# Why do protocol_* methods do not work with Clang + modern GCC-Runtime on Linux?

Tags: objective-c, clang, objective-c-runtime

I tried to switch some of my Objective-C projects from GCC to Clang on Linux.
I used the GCC 4.6.2 runtime because the Clang compiler does not ship with one.
The compiling and linking works, but when using the `protocol_*` methods they do not work.

The following example works fine with GCC but not as expected with Clang:

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

@protocol MyProtocol
+ aClassMethod;
- anInstanceMethod;
@end

void doIt(Protocol *p, SEL sel)
{
    printf("the protocol: %p\n", p);
    if (!p) return;
    printf("the protocol's name: %s\n", protocol_getName(p));
    struct objc_method_description d = protocol_getMethodDescription(p, sel, YES, YES);
    printf("required: YES instance: YES → %p\n", d.name);
    d = protocol_getMethodDescription(p, sel, YES, NO);
    printf("required: YES instance: NO → %p\n", d.name);
    d = protocol_getMethodDescription(p, sel, NO, YES);
    printf("required: NO instance: YES → %p\n", d.name);
    d = protocol_getMethodDescription(p, sel, NO, NO);
    printf("required: NO instance: NO → %p\n", d.name);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Protocol *p1 = @protocol(MyProtocol);
    printf("P1\n");
    printf("class method first:\n");
    doIt(p1, @selector(aClassMethod));
    printf("instance method follows:\n");
    doIt(p1, @selector(anInstanceMethod));

    Protocol *p2 = objc_getProtocol("MyProtocol");
    printf("P2\n");
    printf("class method first:\n");
    doIt(p2, @selector(aClassMethod));
    printf("instance method follows:\n");
    doIt(p2, @selector(anInstanceMethod));

    printf("done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output of the GCC compiled program:

```
P1
class method first:
the protocol: 0x804a06c
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → 0x804b530
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: 0x804a06c
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → 0x804b528
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
P2
class method first:
the protocol: 0x804a06c
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → 0x804b530
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: 0x804a06c
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → 0x804b528
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
done
```

The unexpected output of the Clang compiled program:

```
P1
class method first:
the protocol: 0x804a050
the protocol's name: (null)
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: 0x804a050
the protocol's name: (null)
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
P2
class method first:
the protocol: (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: (nil)
done
```

What's wrong here?
Is there some magical initialization code which will not be called when using Clang?

**[Update]**

When adding an implementation of the protocol like the following the `objc_getProtocol()` method works but the `protocol_*` methods still do not.

```
@interface MyInstance <MyProtocol>
@end

@implementation MyInstance

+ aClassMethod
{
    return nil;
}

- anInstanceMethod
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Is the protocol info exported if your image contains an object `@implementation` which physically adopts the protocol? or is the result the same? example: add `@interface MONObject : SOMEType < MyProtocol > @end \n @implementation MONObject \n @end` then re-run.

Comment: The `protocol_*` methods still do not work with an explicit implementation of the protocol but the `objc_getProtocol` method does.

Comment: What happens if you compile and run [this test](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/test/protocol.m?txt) (don't forget the [header](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437/test/test.h)? If it fails, then there's a potential bug in the implementation.

Comment: I tried with the protocol.m test from the 493.9 version of the Apple runtime you mentioned. Even though it is the GCC runtime I am using the test nearly passes when compiling with GCC (`protocol_getMethodDescription()` does not deliver the identical pointer as `@selector()` and `class_copyPropertyList()` does not work). But it totally fails when compiling with Clang (due to `protocol_getName()` returning `NULL`).

Comment: @TiloPrütz hmmkay. curious. i don't have a proper objc configuration installed on Linux to test this with.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me, not quite sure what you'd be doing differently. What options are you compiling with?

Comment: My compile command line: `/usr/bin/clang -Wall -I /usr/local/gcc-4.6.2/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/include -lobjc -L /usr/local/gcc-4.6.2/lib -o protocol_info.clang protocol_info.m`

Comment: Have you tried [libobjc2](https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-libobjc2) ([FAQ](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ))?  Étoilé/GNUstep have been working on LLVM/Clang compatibility -- in fact Étoilé isn't even supported with GCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my tests, GCC works well with its included GNU libobjc, but Clang works better with GNUstep libobjc2.

GCC 4.6 w/ included GNU libobjc: PASS

```
P1
class method first:
the protocol: 0x602120
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → 0x10eda50
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: 0x602120
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → 0x10eda40
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
P2
class method first:
the protocol: 0x602120
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → 0x10eda50
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: 0x602120
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → 0x10eda40
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
done
```

GCC 4.6 w/ libobjc2 1.6: FAIL

```
P1
class method first:
the protocol: 0x602120
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → 0x6020a0
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: 0x602120
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → 0x6020b0
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
P2
class method first:
the protocol: (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: (nil)
done
```

Clang 3.1 w/ GCC 4.6 GNU libobjc: FAIL

```
P1
class method first:
the protocol: 0x602080
the protocol's name: (null)
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: 0x602080
the protocol's name: (null)
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
P2
class method first:
the protocol: (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: (nil)
done
```

Clang 3.1 w/ libobjc2 1.6: PASS

```
P1
class method first:
the protocol: 0x602080
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: 0x602080
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
P2
class method first:
the protocol: 0x602080
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
instance method follows:
the protocol: 0x602080
the protocol's name: MyProtocol
required: YES instance: YES → (nil)
required: YES instance: NO → (nil)
required: NO instance: YES → (nil)
required: NO instance: NO → (nil)
done
```

Comment: Technically, the question is still not answered. I accepted your answer because it gives a solution to my problem. Tanks.